# Iphone knowing when going back in navigational view control

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm using a navigation based view controller on my iPhone app that uses an RSS feed on-load of a nib to bring back results, then another xml call when you select one. Is there an action when you go back on the second view controller to the first, the reason I ask is that it's reloading the first results again (going off to the server) as it's in the viewdidappear. How do I tell it not to re-load the results?

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code to the `ViewDidLoad` it is only called when the view gets loaded.